# Bypass "field required" validation BUT allow setting binding variables for commandButton?

Tags: commandbutton, required-field, immediate

Title says it all.

- By default (i.e., `immediate="false"`), commandButton `action` doesn't work if the page has
  required fields empty.
- If I put `immediate="true"`, then the binded variables aren't set.

How can I bind variable values on commandButton click, without checking for required fields?

Comment: Setting immediate=true does not fire getters or setters and skips validation.

Comment: @Samir And is there any way to bypass the validation on immediate="false"?

Comment: you can use hierarchical custom setting and add the users/ profiles there for which you want the validation to run or not.Below is the link which will help you achieve this.Let us know if this solves your problem

http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-articles/salesforce-bypass-rules-and-triggers.html

Comment: @Samir sadly it's the standard Lead LastName and Company required fields which are mandatory.

Comment: I don't think you can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Use `<apex:actionRegion>` and keep those required fields OUTSIDE the actionRegion.

Answer (score 1):

I really doubt you can do that, that's the limitation of using `immediate="true"`

But you have some alternatives here:

1. You can write custom code and get every value which you entered on page and then send that data via apex:action function or any other way.
2. As you mentioned in your question, you want to bypass the required field so you can set the required attribute to false on the input tags, like
   `<apex:input value="{!account.name}" required="false"/>`, similarly with other inputs as well.

#### UPDATE

With the second option your mandatory flag will be removed from the field, if you want to retain that, then create your own style class for that flag and use it in code as below:

```
<!-- css for mandatory-flag -->
<style>
  .mandatory-flag{
    border: 1px solid rgb(181, 179, 179);
    border-left: 3px red solid;
    padding: 1px;
  }
</style>
<!-- if you are using dynamic Sobject with dynamic field rendering -->
<apex:variable var="FieldInfo" value="{! $ObjectType[sobjectName].fields[fieldApiName]}" />

<!-- if you are using sobject with fields in usual way -->
<apex:variable var="FieldInfo" value="{! $ObjectType.Account.Fields.Name" />

<apex:inputField styleClass="{!if(FieldInfo.nillable == false,'mandatory-flag','')}" value="fieldObjRef" />
```

you can further customize the CSS to make it more appropriate.

Comment: Point 2 is good - marking this as correct! However, the red highlight for required fields goes away :(

Comment: Well there is still a way to keep that red bar but in order to achieve that you need to add a custom class to the inputField in Dynamic manner, means check field describe property for `isNillable()` and if it comes `false` then add that custom class to inputField.

Comment: @ShumonSaha, Added code for retaining mandatory flag on fields